# Getting rid of "0 - New Lead"?

Tags: leads

I made some custom lead categories, and renamed "0 - New Lead" to "New Lead". However, whenever I run reports for the lead categories, there is both "0 - New Lead" and "New Lead". Is "0 - New Lead" some sort of hardcoded lead status that can't be removed?

Answer (score 0):

If the field is a picklist:

1. Setup -> Customize -> Leads -> Fields
2. Click on "replace" next to the pick list field
3. Enter 0 - New Lead in the replace
4. Select "New Lead" in the replace with

Click OK

Should do it.

Comment: That's exactly what I had done before. There is no such field "0 - New Lead". Only "New Lead". Yet it still shows up in the reports.

Comment: At times like this I dump out the values to Excel and inspect the alleged `0 - New Lead` fields for non-printable blanks or other spurious characters - use the Excel CODE function